# Specify expected outcome in a docstring as hexadecimal?

Tags: python, integer, literals, docstring, doctest

Is there a way to specify expected integer outcomes in a [docstring](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/doctest.html) in hex notation?

```
def identity(val):
    """
    >>> identity(243)
    243
    >>> identity(243)
    0xf3
    """
    return val

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Doctest doesn't interpret the hex notation, resulting in a failure:

```
**********************************************************************
File "hextest.py", line 5, in __main__.identity
Failed example:
    identity(243)
Expected:
    0xf3
Got:
    243
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   1 of   2 in __main__.identity
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
```

I'm aware that I could wrestle the docstring:

```
def identity(val):
    """
    >>> hex(identity(243))
    '0xf3'
    """
    return val
```

But it'd seem natural to have doctest understand [literal integers](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/integers.html) in bases 8, 16 next to decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can write your own [OutputChecker](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html#outputchecker-objects) class to handle numbers however you want:

```python
def identity(val):
    """
    >>> identity(243)
    0xf3
    >>> identity(243)
    243
    """

    return val


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest

    OutputChecker = doctest.OutputChecker

    class HexOutputChecker(OutputChecker):

        def check_output(self, want, got, optionflags):

            if want.startswith('0x'):
                want_str = str(int(want, 16)) + '\n'
                return super().check_output(want_str, got, optionflags)
            else:
                return super().check_output(want, got, optionflags)

    doctest.OutputChecker = HexOutputChecker
    doctest.testmod(verbose=True)
```