# Python doctest match expected with hex notation, without custom OutputChecker

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, docstring, doctest

I commonly work with bytes and hex, and have a bunch of helper methods for working with these numbers.

I am adding `doctest`s into my docstrings, to help make sure they work.  See the below example:

```py
from typing import Tuple


def get_hi_low_bytes(hex_val: int) -> Tuple[int, int]:
    """Separate four hex chars into high and low bytes.

    For example: 0x0424 becomes 0x04, 0x24.

    Preconditions:
        hex_val <= 0xFFFF

    Examples:
        >>> get_hi_low_bytes(0x0424)
        (4, 36)

    How can I make output be:
        (0x04, 0x24)

    """
    return divmod(hex_val, 0x100)
```

Currently, I can't figure out how to get `doctest` to interpret hex notation in the expected (output).  I invoke `doctest` via a [`pytest integration`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/doctest.html).

The question ([Specify expected outcome in a docstring as hexadecimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56392330/specify-expected-outcome-in-a-docstring-as-hexadecimal)) is spot on for what I am looking for.  Unfortunately, the answer is to make a custom [`doctest.OutputChecker`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/doctest.html#outputchecker-objects) that basically converts the `want` to an `int`.

I am wondering, is there some flag I can pass to `doctest` that will enable it to interpret hex notation, without requiring a custom `OutputChecker`?

Comment: `(4, 36)` *is* the output, Python won't print integers in hex without specific instructions. You could have e.g. `>>> get_hi_low_bytes(0x0424) == (0x04, 0x24)`, which would output `True`, or `>>> [hex(x) for x in get_hi_low_bytes(0x0424)]`, which would output `['0x4', '0x24']`.

Comment: The equality test is a great workaround @jonrsharpe, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`doctest` is all about reproducing the Python interactive output. It has some configuration options, mainly concerning output that maybe difficult to match, but as you cannot configure Python to always output hex values instead of decimal values for numbers, there is no reason for doctest to provide such an option.

You can, however, use a custom `OutputChecker`, as described in [Specify expected outcome in a docstring as hexadecimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56392330/specify-expected-outcome-in-a-docstring-as-hexadecimal), in your doctest integration, for example by adding it to your `conftest.py`:

*pytest.ini*

```
[pytest]
addopts = --doctest-modules
```

*conftest.py*

```py
from doctest import OutputChecker
from unittest import mock

import pytest


class HexOutputChecker(OutputChecker):

    def check_output(self, want, got, optionflags):
        if want.startswith('0x'):
            want_str = str(int(want, 16)) + '\n'
            return OutputChecker.check_output(self, want_str, got, optionflags)
        else:
            return OutputChecker.check_output(self, want, got, optionflags)


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def hex_out():
    with mock.patch('doctest.OutputChecker', HexOutputChecker):
        yield
```

*test_doc.py*

```py
def doc():
    """
    >>> 5 * 5
    0x19
    """
    pass
```

Running `pytest -rA test_doc.py` gives:

```
...
=============================================== short test summary info ===============================================
PASSED test_doc.py::test_doc_test.doc
================================================== 1 passed in 0.07s ==================================================
```

Comment: Marching one step closer!  Thank you for providing a great example on how to integrate a `doctest.OutputChecker` into `pytest`. It seems the truth is that the only way to match hex is to use a custom output checker.

Comment: Well, as @jonrsharpe has pointed out, this is not the output that Python gives you, and `doctest` is all about reproducing the Python interactive output. As you cannot configure Python that way, there is no reason for `doctest` to provide such an option. Providing your own output checker is not a big deal, in the end.

Comment: I added that (the last comment) to the answer for clarity.